# Inserting retreived data from query to a new column

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a column of height in foot and inches in the format `6' 7"`

I have used this query to select the names with height in CM and it worked

```
SELECT
    Name,
    (CAST(SUBSTR(Height,1, LOCATE("'",Height)-1) AS UNSIGNED) * 30.48) +
    (CAST(SUBSTR(Height,   LOCATE("'",Height)+1) AS UNSIGNED) * 2.54 )   AS cm
FROM
    active_players_2;
```

I want to insert the data outputted from the previous query into a new Column, I have tried this query but it gives this error

> [22001][1292] Data truncation: Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: ' 5"'

```
ALTER TABLE active_players_2
   ADD Height_cm DECIMAL(10,2) NULL;
UPDATE active_players_2 
SET active_players_2.Height_cm= (CAST(SUBSTR(Height,1, LOCATE("'",Height)-1) AS UNSIGNED) * 30.48) +
            (CAST(SUBSTR(Height,   LOCATE("'",Height)+1) AS UNSIGNED) * 2.54 )
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to remove the `"`

Comment: Why cast as unsigned? it's a small integer. Also, you might be getting the apostrophe symbol, why not use ```LEFT(Height, 1)``` and ```RIGHT(Height, 1)``` ?

Comment: @aymcg31 `RIGHT(Height, 1)` will be the `"` character at the end.

Comment: Conversion errors like this causes a warning in `SELECT` queries, but fatal errors in `UPDATE` queries.

Comment: @Barmar Oops. Not used to the imperial system sorry, you're right

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `"` character after the inches before casting to a number. If you use `SHOW WARNINGS;` after the `SELECT` query you'll see this same error. Many conditions that are only warnings in `SELECT` are turned into errors in `UPDATE` and `INSERT`.

So change:

```
CAST(SUBSTR(Height, LOCATE("'",Height)+1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

to:

```
CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTR(Height, Locate("'", Height) + 1), '"', '') AS UNSIGNED)
```

BTW, you don't actually need to call `CAST()`. When you use a string as a parameter of an arithmetic operator it will automatically be converted to a number.

Comment: I have tried what you said but it now gives invalid values such as 336 cm, however only the 6' 6'' values are valid in the result as 198.12

Comment: Can you give an example value that produces invalud results?

Comment: So 6' 5'' turn into 314.96 cm which is invalid

Comment: I had parentheses misplaced. I've updated the answer and included the `UPDATE` statement.